# In a convex n-gon ( n≥4) no three diagonals intersect at one point. Prove that the number...

Tags: convex-analysis, problem-solving

Here is the problem I've faced with.

> In a convex n-gon (n≥4), no three diagonals intersect at the same point. Prove that the number of all intersection points of the diagonals is equal to the number of quadrilaterals whose vertices are all vertices of a given n-gon.

I've tried to search the solution in a browser and actually I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days, but I can't. So, how to solve that, and what is the algorithm to the solution ?

*Be aware that this is only 8-grade problem. And this one is from the "Finite sets. Mutually unambiguous correspondence" topic*.

Comment: @peterwhy, that's the stupid translation, sorry and thanks. I've replaced the mistake.

Comment: Can you prove a bijection between: 1) intersection points of the diagonals, and 2) quadrilaterals whose vertices are all vertices of the given $n$-gon?

Comment: @peterwhy nope, I can't, I have no idea how to do that

Comment: This is only true if restricted to convex quadrilaterals and diagonals whose intersections are in the interior of the $n$-gon. If you allow diagonals which share a common endpoint, then the number of such intersections is the sum of the number of all convex quadrilaterals and the number of all triangles whose vertices are vertices of the $n$-gon. (Though the convexity of the quadrilaterals is guaranteed by that of the $n$-gon, provided you don't allow self-intersecting quadrilaterals.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any 4 points in the n-gon. Call them A, B, C, and D going around the n-gon clockwise. Note that there is exactly one quadrilateral defined by these 4 points, ABCD, and there is exactly one intersection caused by the segments AB, BC, CD, DA, AC, and BD, namely the intersection between AC and BD. Clearly, there is a bijection between any 4 points and the quadrilateral they define, and because of the no-3-lines-intersecting rule there is also a bijection between any intersection point and the 4 endpoints of the 2 lines that intersect there, so there is a one-to-one correspondence and we are done.

Comment: This is a step in solving a problem from Leo Moser's 1949 "On the dangers of induction" (Math. Mag. 109).  The number of regions in the circle determined by the (n choose 2) chords is given by the sequence 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, *31*...

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I couldn't come up with that.

Comment: Glad i could help!